# WinAPI. Как Включать/отключать Toolbar кнопки TBBUTTON

Tags: winapi

Взял за пример код из документации

```
HWND CreateSimpleToolbar(HWND hWndParent)
{
    HIMAGELIST g_hImageList = NULL;
    const int ImageListID = 0;
    const int numButtons = 7;
    const int bitmapSize = 16;

    const DWORD buttonStyles = BTNS_AUTOSIZE;

    hWndToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL,WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE, 0, 0, 0, 0,global::hwnd, NULL, global::hInst, NULL);

    if (hWndToolbar == NULL)
        return NULL;

    g_hImageList = ImageList_Create(bitmapSize, bitmapSize, ILC_COLOR16 | ILC_MASK, numButtons, 0);


    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST,(WPARAM)ImageListID,        (LPARAM)g_hImageList);
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_LOADIMAGES,  (WPARAM)IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR,(LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL);

            tbButtons[0] = { MAKELONG(STD_FILENEW,    ImageListID), IDM_FILE_OPEN,  TBSTATE_ENABLED, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"New" };
            tbButtons[1] = { MAKELONG(STD_FILEOPEN,   ImageListID), IDM_FILE_OPEN,  TBSTATE_ENABLED, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Open" };
            tbButtons[2] = { MAKELONG(STD_FILESAVE,   ImageListID), IDM_EXPORT,     0, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Save" };
            tbButtons[3] = { MAKELONG(STD_UNDO,       ImageListID), IDM_UNDO,       0, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Undo" };
            tbButtons[4] = { MAKELONG(STD_REDOW,      ImageListID), IDM_REDO,       0, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Redo" };
            tbButtons[5] = { MAKELONG(STD_PROPERTIES, ImageListID), IDM_EXPORT,     0, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Mode" };
            tbButtons[6] = { MAKELONG(STD_HELP,       ImageListID), IDM_EXPORT,     0, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Help" };




    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_ADDBUTTONS,       (WPARAM)numButtons,       (LPARAM)& tbButtons);


    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
    ShowWindow(hWndToolbar, TRUE);

    return hWndToolbar;
}
```

TBBUTTON массив, и hWndToolbar сделал глобальными в файле, надеясь что это поможет включать\выключать возможность нажатия кнопки, таким образом он не работает:

```
tbButtons[2].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    tbButtons[3].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    tbButtons[4].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    tbButtons[5].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
```

При загруженном файле должны открываться все кнопки, а не загруженном - только  STD_FILENEW и STD_FILEOPEN, остальные кнопки как и меню, должны быть недоступными (серыми). Как это сделать в Toolbar?

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает сообщение `TB_ENABLEBUTTON`?

Comment: Не знал о нем, уже разобрался. Все делается через сообщения типа SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_ENABLEBUTTON, (WPARAM)IDM_UNDO, (LPARAM) MAKELONG(TRUE, 0));